# CSS3 Skewing DIV issue

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to skew a **div**, something similar to what **https://digital.scotch.io/** has but actually it's not coming out right.

```css
.skew1:before {
  content:' ';
  display: block;
  height: 400px;
  width: 100%;
  background: black;
  padding: 50px 0;
  -webkit-transform: skewY(-2deg) translateZ(0);
  -moz-transform: skewY(-2deg) translateZ(0);
  -ms-transform: skewY(-2deg) translateZ(0);
  -o-transform: skewY(-2deg) translateZ(0);
  transform: skewY(-2deg) translateZ(0);
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: -10px;
  z-index: -1;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="container skew1">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <h2>This is my skew1!</h2>
      </div>
    </div>  
  </div>  
</section>
```

Not really sure what I'm doing wrong. This is my **[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/labanino/xqwdx8jz/embedded/result/)**. Any help please? Thanks.

Comment: What exactly is not coming out right you think?

Comment: @c-smile Well, I have three divs, black, red and blue and the are on top of each other. I want the divs to be displayed in a block label.

Comment: What is "in a block label" exactly? As for now you have skewed boxes with no text ( content:' '; ) inside.

Comment: @c-smile https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements. The boxes have an h2 in it, but it could be anything. Sorry for the typo, I meant block-level.

Comment: The boxes have *no* h2 in them as you use :before pseudo-element that is placed exactly "before" the boxes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you need is not skewing. you need to set a 3d perspective to the div and rotate it on its Y axis:

```css
.container {
  margin-top: 20px;
  width: 500px;
  height: 150px;
  position: relative;
  perspective: 800px;
}
.container2 {
  margin: 5px 82px;
  width: 500px;
  height: 150px;
  position: relative;
  perspective: 800px;
}
.container .inner {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  background: red;
  transform: rotateY(-45deg);
}
.container2 .inner {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  background: blue;
  transform: rotateY(45deg);
}
```

```html
<section class="container">
  <div class="inner"></div>
</section>
<section class="container2">
  <div class="inner"></div>
</section>
```

Comment: Let's try that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The **div** wrapping the text needed to be `position: relative;`(*check the original code*) and also needed some `height` and `padding` to align the text vertically. This is the **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/labanino/xqwdx8jz/8/embedded/result/)**.

[image]